# Basic Analysis on Functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f$ be a $C^1$ function defined on $\Bbb{R}$. Let $-\infty<a<b<+\infty$. Suppose that $f(a)=f(b)=0$ and that $f>0$ on $(a,b)$ and that $f<0$ on $(b,+\infty)$. Let $x_{0}\in(b,+\infty)$. Show that $$x(t,x_0)\in(b,+\infty)$$
> for each $t\in I(x_0)$ and that $I(x_0)=(\alpha,+\infty)$ for some $-\infty\leq\alpha<0$.

I have attempted to tackle the first part of the problem, and here is my progress (though am unsure whether it is correct):

We prove by contradiction. Let $a=0$ and $b=1$. Suppose that $x(t,x_0)\notin(1,+\infty)$ for some $t\in I(x_0)$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem there exists a $s\in I(x_0)$ such that $x(s,x_0)$ takes the value $1$. But since $1$ is an equilibrium point from $f(b)=0$, the orbit of $x_0$ must lie in the set $\{1\}$, which is a contradiction from $x_0\in(b,+\infty)$.

Not too sure on how to proceed with the second part of the problem, appreciate any pointers I can get - thanks.

Comment: What is the link between $f$ and $x$? I imagine that this is about ODE. If so, it would be good to provide the full picture.

Comment: What is $x(t, x_0)$?